# Object pooling in Multiplayer Game. Physics not synchronizing well

Tags: unity, unity-networking

I implemented object pooling for my multiplayer project. Following [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetCustomSpawning.html) I used custom spawn handler for shooting bullets. Bullets game object has rigidbody so selected **Sync Rigibody 3D** in Network Transfrom. My pool size is 5.

While shooting when all 5 projectile is shooted then they have to have to come back to initial position one by one that is the concept of pooling.

When projectile moving back they just instantly go back to initial position on **host** but on **client** their position are lerping and can easily be seen that we are reusing projectile.

How will I fix this ?
I've added GIF for better understanding
[image: I've added GIF for better understanding]

Code For SpawnManager where I'am using Custom SpawnHandler

```
public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour {

public int m_ObjectPoolSize = 10;
public GameObject m_Prefab;
public GameObject[] m_Pool;

private Queue<GameObject> objectPool;
public NetworkHash128 assetId { get; set; }

public delegate GameObject SpawnDelegate(Vector3 position, NetworkHash128 assetId);
public delegate void UnSpawnDelegate(GameObject spawned);

void Start()
{
    assetId = m_Prefab.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().assetId;

    objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_ObjectPoolSize; ++i)
    {
        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(m_Prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        obj.SetActive(false);
        objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
    }

    ClientScene.RegisterSpawnHandler(assetId, SpawnObject, UnSpawnObject);
}

public GameObject GetFromPool(Vector3 position)
{
    GameObject obj = objectPool.Dequeue();
    obj.transform.position = position;
    obj.SetActive(true);
    objectPool.Enqueue(obj);

    return obj;
}

public GameObject SpawnObject(Vector3 position, NetworkHash128 assetId)
{
    return GetFromPool(position);
}
// Not calling this function yet
public void UnSpawnObject(GameObject spawned)
{
    Debug.Log("Re-pooling GameObject " + spawned.name);
    spawned.SetActive(false);
}
```

}

And this is the code where I am calling these function.

```
public class PlayerTest : NetworkBehaviour {

SpawnManager spawnManager;

private void Start()
{
    spawnManager = GameObject.Find("Spawn Manager").GetComponent<SpawnManager>();
}

private void Update() {

    if (!isLocalPlayer) return;

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {

        CmdFire();
    }
}

[Command]
void CmdFire() {

    // Set up prefab on server
    var prefab = spawnManager.GetFromPool(transform.position + transform.forward);
    prefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * 4;

    // spawn prefab on client and server
    NetworkServer.Spawn(prefab, spawnManager.assetId);
}
```

Comment: Check this article for smooth physics syncing: https://forum.unity.com/threads/success-smooth-physics-rigidbody-transform-syncing-using-unet.458027/

Comment: Please share your code for the custom spawn handler. There's formatting for `code` available.

Comment: @Nick I've read the artical, really informative. Looks like I have to make custom NetworkTransform. Could you suggest me how would I start creating custom NetworkTranform or any blog link about it.

Comment: @Stephan I've updated question with code.

Comment: @AbhinaySinghNegi Network transfrom is pretty easy thing to write in unity, main idea is simple, server moves object, sends new position(or change in position) to clients, which then sync it with server using simple lerp for example, or in your case they use some other algorithm, like in article. I've not done physics syncing myself yet, but if you are new to it, try first learning how to use unitys cmd and rpc functions well, also i imagine this article has many useful info on it too.

Comment: @Nick Ok I'll learn those concepts and try, whenever I will solve this I'll add the answer.

Comment: @AbhinaySinghNegi that will be very useful!